# How do I integrate PHP and HTML so that passwords are not visible?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

As mentioned in the title, I am attempting to combine PHP and HTML so that my passwords are not visible.

My code is:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "**************";
    $pass = "**************";
    $databaseName = "**************";
    $tableName = "**************";
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
    $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $json_string = json_decode(json_encode($array), true);
    $ID = $json_string['ID'];
    $ENOM_UserID = $json_string["ENOM_UserID"];
    $ENOM_Password = $json_string["ENOM_Password"];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/jquery/v2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Client example </h2>
    <h3>Output: </h3>
    <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>

    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $('#output').html("<b>ID: </b>" + $ID + "<b> UserName: </b>" + $ENOM_UserID + "<b> Password: </b>" + $ENOM_Password);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I reference those variables defined in the PHP section above?

Comment: your question is vague. what are you trying to do here anyway? why not just `echo` those fetched values, avoid `mysql_*` API, and plain naked passwords, use `password_hash` if available

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Whats with the `json_decode()`...?

Comment: You can't access PHP variables from a jQuery script unless you use an AJAX call, or simply echo them into your JavaScript code. Bear in  mind that anything you send to the client can be seen by someone interested in doing so, so do all your password checking in a secure place: on the server.

Comment: I have to send a username and a password to a third party api. The api uses this information in plain text. I am trying to not expose that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML contents, wrap the PHP variables into PHP tags, otherwise they will be treated as regular HTML content.

```
<?php echo $ID?>
```

or

```
<?=$ID?>
```

So the jQuery call might look like this:

```
$('#output').html("<b>ID: </b><?=$ID?><b> UserName: </b><?=$ENOM_UserID?><b> Password: </b><?=$ENOM_Password?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide your password with another character, simply use

```
<?php preg_replace('/./','*',$ENOM_Password)?>
```

So the jquery part should be like this:

```
$('#output').html("<b>ID: </b><?=$ID?><b> UserName: </b><?=$ENOM_UserID?><b> Password: </b><?php preg_replace('/./','*',$ENOM_Password)?>");
```